# How can i get the last lines of string in JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

```
$GPGGA,013810.000,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,1,10,1.0,26.4,M,39.1,M,,0000*69
$GPRMC,013810.000,A,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,0.00,122.34,200916,,,A*6A
$GPGGA,013811.000,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,1,10,1.0,26.4,M,39.1,M,,0000*69
$GPRMC,013811.000,A,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,0.00,122.34,200916,,,A*6A
$GPGGA,013812.000,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,1,10,1.0,26.4,M,39.1,M,,0000*69
$GPRMC,013812.000,A,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,0.00,122.34,200916,,,A*6A
```

Every Second I'm concatenating String of NMEA to a String Variable. All I want is to get the last $GPGGA and GPRMC because i need it for time and date. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Split on line terminators and use the last element returned.

Comment: what is line terminator sir? sorry i`m just a newbie in java development, by the way they are all in 1 String variable.

Comment: You can use the lastIndexOf function of String for finding the last occurence of $GPRMC AND $GPGGA and then substring your string with comma and then take only 11 items of that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following:

```
String a = "$GPGGA,013812.000,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,1,10,1.0,26.4,M,39.1,M,,0000*69";
String b = "$GPRMC,013812.000,A,1437.9098,N,12100.2297,E,0.00,122.34,200916,,,A*6A";
```

Then split each at the "," symbol:

```
String[] aAry = a.split(",");
String[] bAry = b.split(",");
```

I think the second element of each array (index 1) contains the time so it can be accessed as `aAry[1]` which contains the string 013812.000 (as does `bAry[1]`). I'm not sure where the date is stored in these strings.

Comment: Sir they are all in one variable. im concatenating it every second. how can i get the last $GPGGA and $GPRMC?

Comment: the date is in the $GPRMC line, it is 200916 where the format is MMDDYY.

Comment: If the String which contains the concatenated Strings is named `bigString`, then `String[] stringArray = bigString.split("\n");` and `stringArray[stringArray.size()-1]` will return the last String. Then the date and time can be removed from the last String as needed.

Comment: Depending on the system you are using, you may need to use `\r` instead of `\n`. I Suppose you could also use the `$` symbol for the split as an alternate.

Comment: why i got error when im getting the size of the array sir?

Comment: cannot find symbol ... symbol: method size()